# java FileNotFoundException while reading config xml file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I need to read a config.xml file from my DYNAMIC WEB PROJECT.
I have placed my file in the folder structure MyProj/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/config.xml folder.
When I print the absolute path of the file
 new File(config.xml).getAbsolutePath()
its checking for the eclipse home directory(C:\Temp\eclipse\eclipse) rather than my project home directory(C:\Temp\MyProj).
Because of this I am getting the issue  FIleNotFoundException.
How can I tell eclipse to check for the file from my project directory?

USing tomcat 7 in eclipse IDE.

Comment: we need a lot more information from you. how are you building this project? Please, start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: have added few more details.

Comment: i asked you how you're building this project. you haven't mentioned that. this is actually something in the project preferences that needs to be fixed. you shouldn't be putting it in the WEB-INF/classes folder anyway. if you put it in the right place and the project is set up correctly not only will eclipse find it it will auto-magically put it in the right place for your build

Comment: i dint understand what you expect from building project..and i knwo its some silly mistake that i have made in my eclipse which is why eclipse is not checking teh correct path.I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: do you use maven or gradle or anything like this? are you doing a manual export? what are you doing here?

Comment: i am not using any such tools to build my project.not even spring framework.

Comment: just so you know, spring framework isn't a build tool. you should consider right-clicking and selecting convert to maven project, and then putting your config.xml file in the src/main/resources dir after that. that might rock your world

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a dynamic web application it means you should respect JEE rules and one these rules is: do not use Files but use resources. Your web application will be deployed within a web container (like Tomcat) which can be installed anywhere. By accessing config files as resources, they are searched in the classpath which is more flexible and independent from the absolute file location of your web application or container.

If you put the config.xml in WEB-INF/classes it will be in your classpath.
You should access it as a resource and not as a file.

I suggest you improve your knowledge about how resources are managed and accessed in java.

Within a class you can do:

```
InputStream configInput=this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml");
```

As it seams to be an XML file, you can read it using an XML parser:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
...
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.xml"));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't be manually putting a file in WEB-INF/classes . you should put it in the right place in your project structure according to how you are building your project and eclipse will place it there for you.

you're missing answering the over all question as there is clearly something wrong in the project set up.

Comment: @DieNerd I know you should not put files in WEB-INF/classes yourself. That's also why I suggest to learn more about resource management. Once user9450093 understands the use of src/main/resources, my proposed solution remains the same and is a valid response to user9450093's question. The point I want to make is that you should access resources as InputStreams in stead of Files.